# how to change identity increment of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following statement can reset seed

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('TableName', RESEED, 1)

but this time I have to change its increment .

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Sql Server Management Studio:

[image: Identity Increment in Sql Server Management Studio]

Using this approach will most likely recreate the table.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
 ALTER TABLE MyCustomers 
 ALTER COLUMN CustId IDENTITY (200, 2)
```

Code from ms-help://MS.VSCC.v90/MS.MSDNQTR.v90.en/ssmprog3/html/5719d3e4-14db-4073-bed7-d08f39416a39.htm

Comment: this is a 'documentation' bug.  suggested syntax will fail. you cannot ALTER the increment value for an identity. you must drop/re-create the column or table

Answer (score 0):

We can't update a column's identity to increment by 2 on each entry. The easiest method is to create another table with IDENTITY(1,2) and move the data to that table before dropping the actual table. Please go through the script below.

Let TableA is our actual table.

1. CREATE TABLE TableB(col1 INT IDENTITY (1,2) NOT NULL, col2 VARCHAR(10) NULL);
2. INSERT INTO TableB SELECT col2 FROM TableA;
3. DROP TABLE TableA;
4. sp_rename TableB, TableA;

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the auto increment to a higher value by

1. Set IDENTITY_INSERT off
2. Running an insert statement with ID set to where you want to continue from
3. Set IDENTITY_INSERT on
4. Delete the row created (assuming it was only done to increment seed)

For example;

Table 'People' with last ID = 10 can be set to continue from 400,000 by;

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT AccessToken off
insert into People(Id, name) values (400000,'Bob')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT AccessToken on
Delete from People where ID = 400000
```